# There's a problem when I try to connect Eclipse to MySQL database (Specify Driver)

Tags: mysql, eclipse

[image: An error has occurred. See error log for more details. com/ibm/icu/util/StringTokenizer]
The error is:

> An error has occurred. See error log for more details.com/ibm/icu/util/StringTokenizer

How can I fix this? I can't enter a driver name

I tried downgrading the JDK to version 17 but that didn't help.

Comment: Was this a fresh installation, or one that's been upgraded to the version you haven't mentioned?

Comment: @nitind If I understand you correctly, the fresh one

Comment: That's going to need a bug reported, then. I've only seen a similar issue in upgraded installations.

Comment: I have the same problem trying to add a PostgreSQL driver

in my case is in an upgrated version